# Detect looping stream

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, iptv

How can I detect a looping iptv stream?
I've tried solve it by ffprobe:

```
ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_streams -print_format json -pretty 'http://linktostream'
```

But didn't get needed data.

Comment: what do you mean by looping iptv stream??

Comment: Looping 10-15 seconds video

Comment: You mean wanto loop first 15 second of video?

Answer (score 0):

If the server is simply serving the video and then restarting it at the end to create the loop, then you will most likely need to analyse the byte streams itself. In other words choose a point in the video stream and save 50 bytes from the byte stream and then monitor the stream until you see the same byes again.

If the video itself is looped, i.e. if you download the entire video it will be 100 mins long, but the content every 10 seconds is the same, then you could analyse frames using something like OpenCV (https://opencv.org) - for example store the first 10 frames and then compare each frame after that to see if it matches one. As soon as you find a match hacek that the next frames also matches and you should have found the loop period.

In both cases if the video is encrypted then it may be harder - the byte stream approach will still probably work but you will not be able to eat and compare individual frames.